# Php coded text decoding

Tags: php

into a string, i have some coded text.

```
...
f&#252;r
...
```

it is a german word "für".

How can I transform the whole Text to german text?

Thanks for help.

Comment: [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an HTML specific encoding so:

```
echo html_entity_decode('f&#252;r'); // returns für
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php